# Prevent MySQL user from creating/deleting databases

Tags: mysql

We are working on a UI panel that will manage the creation/altering/deletion of MySQL users and databases. To prevent out-of-sync situations, we would like to disable the creation/deletion of MySQL databases for MySQL users.

Our 'global' users - that can access all databases that starts with its username - have the capability to create and drop databases currently. This is how the privileges for the global user looks like (this is not an admin/root user):

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `testtt`@`%`
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testtt\_%`.* TO `testtt`@`%`
```

I know the creation of databases can be disabled within PHPMyAdmin, but I feel more confident to configure this in the PRIVILEGES of a specific user. I'm having a hard time finding out which PRIVILEGE we need to revoke or alter in order to prevent users from having the ability to create/delete databases.

Hopefully you can help us out!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Privilege Restriction Using Partial Revokes.

The partial_revokes system variable controls whether privilege restrictions can be placed on accounts. To permit the REVOKE operation, enable partial_revokes:

```
SET PERSIST partial_revokes = ON;

mysql> REVOKE UPDATE ON mysql.* FROM u1;
mysql> REVOKE DELETE ON world.* FROM u1;
```

As of MySQL 8.0.16, that is possible if the partial_revokes system variable is enabled. Specifically, for users who have privileges at the global level.

For a better understanding of it, refer to the documentation:-
[partial-revokes in MYSQL DB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/8.0/en/partial-revokes.html)

Comment: Interesting, we run on version 8.0.25, so that might be sufficient. I've attempted to apply `REVOKE UPDATE ON mysql.* FROM 'testtt'@'%'`, however it returns an error `#1141 - There is no such grant defined for user 'testtt' on host '%'`. Probably because we haven't applied grants for the mysql database, we don't want user so see the contents of this database.